# Counting days by non standard days end

Tags: mysql, datetime

I am trying to count events that happen in a day, which in itself is easy:

```
SELECT date(time),COUNT(DISTINCT comment)
FROM data
GROUP BY date(time)
```

But I need a day end to be set at 4pm. So all comments before 4pm is day N, and news after 4pm are day N+1. This isnt a global thing, so I'd rather not change time zone of entire program and etc. Maybe I can somehow apply timezone to this query or pad time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  DATE_ADD(date(time),
    INTERVAL case when time(time)>='16:00:00' then 1 else 0 end DAY) as day,
    COUNT(DISTINCT comment)
FROM data
GROUP BY day
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
SELECT date(time + INTERVAL 8 HOUR) as day, COUNT(DISTINCT comment)
FROM data
GROUP BY day
```

You want your days to end at 4PM, or 8 hours early so, we add 8 hours to `time`, forcing the date to roll over at 4PM.

Comment: produces same result a one above, so both seem to work! thanks

Comment: If your table is small it doesn't matter, but did you test performance?

Comment: yeap, the are nearly identical every time